# Can I get file.OpenStreamForReadAsync() from file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, storagefile

I am still learning the tricks of read/write file streams and hope someone could help if what I am looking for is feasible.

The code below makes WebApi calls (note `GetAsync()` on line 2) to get an image file Id and save downloaded file to database with computed Md5Hash. The code works fine, but in the interest of efficiency I was wondering if it's possible to get `file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()` from `file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()` (not sure even if this is possible, but I can see some extension methods that operate on a stream but no luck with attempts I've made so far). If this is possible, I can avoid saving a file and opening it again, by instead making the GetMD5Hash() method call within the `using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()){ ... }` block.

Can I have the equivalent of `Utils.GetMD5Hash(stream);`, shown below outside the `using` block, inside the block, the intention being to avoid opening the file outside of the `using` block?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri($"{url}{imageId}")); // call to WebApi; url and imageId defined earlier

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync())
    {
        var stream = contentStream.AsStreamForRead();
        var file = await imagesFolder.CreateFileAsync(imageFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, 4096);

            // >>>> At this point, from the Write fileStream, can I get the equivalent of file.OpenStreamForReadAsync() ??

        }

        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        string md5Hash = await Utils.GetMD5Hash(stream);
        await AddImageToDataBase(file, md5Hash);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MemoryStream` is read/write, so if all you wanted to do was to compute the hash, something like this should do the trick:

```
var stream = contentStream.AsStreamForRead();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string md5Hash = await Utils.GetMD5Hash(ms);
}
```

But since you want to save the file anyway (it's passed to `AddImageToDataBase`, after all), consider

- Save to the `MemoryStream`
- Reset the memory stream
- Copy the memory stream to the file stream
- Reset the memory stream
- Compute the hash

I'd suggest you do performance measurements, though. The OS does cache file I/O, so it's unlikely that you'd actually have to do a physical disk read to compute the hash. The performance gains might not be what you imagine.

Comment: You put me on the right track, thank you. I am posting a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete answer using `MemoryStream` as **Petter Hesselberg** suggested in his answer. Take note of a couple of tricky situations that I had to encounter, to do what I wanted to do: (1) make sure `fileStream` is made Disposable with `using` block, and (2) make sure `MemoryStream` is set to start with `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before using it, both for the file to be saved and for the MemoryStream object handed over for computing MD5Hash.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri($"{url}{imageId}")); // call to WebApi; url and imageId defined earlier

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync())
    {
        var stream = contentStream.AsStreamForRead();
        var file = await imagesFolder.CreateFileAsync(imageFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await ms.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // rewind for next use below
            }

            string md5Hash = await Utils.GetMD5Hash(ms);
            await AddImageToDataBase(file, md5Hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried any performance measurements?

Comment: I will do that and report back. I'm interrupted by something else at the moment.